# Kotlin Efficient way of Toggling an item in a list

Tags: android, list, kotlin, collections, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a toggleItem algorithm which removes/adds item from/to a recyclerview items list. It was optimised by a friend of mine to reduce the code smell that comes with `!!` .

I'm looking for alternative / minimal ways I can write this simple algorithm, with the awesome kotlin collections operations that we have. What's your optimum/minimal alternative to these two?

.

(ItemType is an enum class, as a tag of initialised item)

Original:

```
fun toggleItem(itemType: ItemType, show: Boolean) {
        val item = _allItems.value?.find { it.type == itemType }
        item?.let {
            if (!show) _carouselItems.value = _carouselItems.value!!.minus(it)
        } ?: if (show) _carouselItems.value = _carouselItems.value!!.plus(item!!)

    }
```

Further optimised :

```
fun toggleItem(itemType: ItemType, show: Boolean) {
    if (show) {
        val item = _allItems.value?.find { it.type == itemType }
        item?.let {
            _carouselItems.value = _carouselItems.value?.plus(it)?.distinct()?.sortedBy { it.type }
        }
    } else
        _carouselItems.value = _carouselItems.value?.filter { it.type != itemType }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m inferring that `_allItems` and `_carouselItems` are both of type `MutableLiveData<List<ItemType>?>` or something very similar. You can replace your `!!` with an Elvis operator and default value to avoid the long chain of null-safe calls. It also is clearer to use an empty list to represent no data rather than using null so I would make the LiveData’s type non-nullable.

You can use the Elvis operator to do an early return / smart-cast in this case to avoid the use of `let`. A little more readable this way, in my opinion.

```
fun toggleItem(itemType: ItemType, show: Boolean) {
    val currentItems = _carouselItems.value ?: emptyList()
    if (show) {
        val item = _allItems.value?.find { it.type == itemType }
            ?: return
        _carouselItems.value = (currentItems + item).distinct().sortedBy { it.type }
    } else
        _carouselItems.value = currentItems.filter { it.type != itemType }
    }
}
```

If you know the item should always be in the all items list, this could be more concise:

```
fun toggleItem(itemType: ItemType, show: Boolean) {
    val item = _allItems.value?.find { it.type == itemType }
        ?: return
    val currentItems = _carouselItems.value ?: emptyList()
    _carouselItems.value = when {
            show -> (currentItems + item).distinct().sortedBy { it.type }
            else -> currentItems - item
        }
}
```

You might also consider transitioning to StateFlow. It is a similar concept to LiveData, except that it enforces a beginning value, so its `value` parameter is not nullable if the type isn't nullable. But you should be familiar with coroutine basics first.

Answer (score 0):

Both are ok when data set is small, but the computation will increase quickly as the data size grows.

```kotlin
// store visibility value to a map using ItemType as its keys
val _toggles: Map<ItemType, Boolean> = mapOf(ItemType.One to false, ItemType.Two to true); 

fun toggleItem(itemType: ItemType, show: Boolean) {
    _toggles[itemType] = show
    val list = _allItem.values?.filter(item -> _toggles[item.type]) ?: listOf()
    _carouselItems.value = list
}
```